# Android: Accessing a global Variable inside an onClickListener

Tags: java, android, global-variables

So in Android/Java, I need to access a global variable that is an `EditText[]`that I create above the `onCreate` method of my activity inside of an `onClickListener`. Here is the variable:

```
public class NCDTCPRelayActivity extends Activity {
     final EditText[] relayLabelEdits = new EditText[n];
```

Where `n` is another global variable integer.

My problem is that in order to access these `EditText` inside an `onclickListener` i had to make final to access inside the onClickListener, but I need to assign `relayLabelEdits` to a new `EditText[]` if the value of n changes which it is wont to do.

Below is the `onClickListener` (the main portion of the app is to open a tcp socket and control relays via WiFi so just ignore the socket information and those System.out.println that point to the `relayLabelEdits` return null unless the `relayLabelEdits` variable is final):

```
    Button save = new Button(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText[] saveTargets = relayLabelEdits;
            System.out.println("Direct: " + relayLabelEdits[0]);
            System.out.println("first try " + saveTargets[0]);



            //Creates string to create the database names on the fly
            String relayToSave;

            int myNum = 0;
            try {
                myNum = Integer.parseInt(portEditText.getText().toString());
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The Port Number you entered must only contain numbers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(ipAEditText.getText().toString());
            cPanel.saveString("ipA", ipAEditText.getText().toString());
            cPanel.saveInt("port", myNum);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                relayToSave = "relay" + (i+1);
                System.out.println("HERE I AM");
                System.out.println(relayLabelEdits[i]);
                cPanel.saveString(relayToSave, relayLabelEdits[i].getText().toString());
                //cPanel.saveString(relayToSave, "It worked");
                System.out.println("HERE I AM");
            }

            if (cPanel.connect() == true){
                createMainContainer();
                setContentView(sView);
                getRelayNames();
                displayRelayNames();
                updateButtonText();
            }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Could Not Connect, check IP address and Port Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

So any ideas on how I can access the `EditText[]` inside the `onClickListener` without making it final?

Comment: Just to clarify, there is no such thing as global variables in Java. `relayLabelEdits` is an ordinary class member with package scope. (That looks wrong to me. Why do you want to do that?)

Comment: So I can create an array of EditTexts in a for loop that will scale with the number of relays they have on the tcp server side.

Comment: How would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make the listener a class outside and pass the activity reference to it?

Comment: I'll have to look up how to do that, I've only used the nested ones. I'm fairly new to android so I haven't got a lot of the particulars down. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok that worked great. Can't believe I didn't think to try it.